# How do I get a menu to go on top of everything?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, header

I am trying to have a menu that takes up 100vh when the menu button is clicked. However, I also have a header at the top so the menu content is lower than it. How do I make the `menu` go on top of the `header`? I'm trying to do this without making the header `display: none` because I want it to be shown on the side - in the left over space from making the `menu` have a `view width` of 80vw.

```css
header {
  height: 3.4rem;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

.menu-container {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <img src="img/user.png" alt="">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-xl"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <div class="top-menu">
      <a href="">Premium</a>
      <a href="">Support</a>
      <a href="">Download</a>
      <div class="menu-line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-menu">
      <a href="">Account</a>
      <a href="">Log out</a>
    </div>
    <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</nav>
```

(I did not add all the CSS to do with the `menu` and `header` because the rest of it is irrelevant.)

How do I move the `menu` to go on top?

Comment: With the provided snippets, everything just stacks vertically without any overlapping areas. Please ensure to provide a [minimal, reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `position: relative` is not set properly, it should only be on a parent that contains both `header` and `nav`. And then set the following css :

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80vw;
}
```

Add margin and background if you want.

Now `nav` should be above `header`.

Comment: Thanks this worked well. I didn't need the `z-index` after all.

Comment: You're welcome :) Indeed `z-index` isn't necessary with this solution.

Comment: Actually, I ended up adding `z-index: 1` because if I didn't it would only show on top of the `header` not everything but I didn't have to add `z-index` to anything else, just the `nav` section. It would work whether position was `fixed` or `absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue lies in the position and z-index of your .menu and header css. Try making the position: absolute for both absolute and change the z-index of menu to 1 and header to 2 so that it shows menu on top of header.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Thanks this worked! I just needed to make it absolute for both.

Comment: Great glad that I could help!